# queue underlying c clear not support on vs2008

Tags: c++11, queue

```
#include <queue>

struct model_shell_t 
{
    model_shell_t() {clear();}
    void    clear();
    void    Release() {clear(); model_pool._delete(this);}
    void    SetArgument(byte4 _type, byte4 _arg1, byte4 _arg2) 
    {
        switch( _type )
        {
        case 100:
            if( tail_enable && !_arg1 )
            {
                tail_deque.clear();//tail_queue.c.clear(); // Error C2248 Cannot access protected member of queue
            }
            tail_enable = _arg1;
            break;
        case 101:
            tail_interval = _arg1;
            tail_count = _arg2;
            break;
        }
    }

    queue<model_t>  tail_queue;
    byte4           tail_enable;
    byte4           tail_interval;
    byte4           tail_count;
    deque<model_t>  tail_deque;
};
```

Another :

```
for( byte4 i = 0; i < ms->tail_queue.size(); i++ )
        {
            //ms->tail_queue.c[i].bind_model = &bind_ms->tail_queue.c[i];
            ms->tail_deque[i].bind_model = &bind_ms->tail_deque[i];
        }
```

> error C2248: 'std::queue<_Ty>::c' : cannot access protected member
>   declared in class 'std::queue<_Ty>'

When i upgrade solution from VS2003 to VS2008 i cant use clear() function.
How can i use it ?
Thank you

EDITED : With help from Igor Tandetnik i have change above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2003 was wrong, VS2008 is right. The underlying container should be a protected member, and shouldn't be accessible. Your code relies on a non-conforming implementation detail - essentially, on a compiler bug that has since been fixed.

As you apparently need direct access to elements, you are breaking queue abstraction anyway. It'd be easiest to just use `std::deque` directly, without a wrapper.

If for some reason you insist on using `std::queue`, another approach would be for `model_shell_t` to privately derive from it, rather than having it as a member. This way it'll have direct access to `c`. Though it's unclear why you would want to take such a circuitous route to getting a `std::deque` member.

Comment: Should i declare deque<model_t> tail_deque; instead of queue<model_t> tail_queue then  change tail_queue.c.clear(); to tail_deque.clear(); ?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the easiest, most direct approach.

Comment: Nice, It's okay now! Thank you very much sir :D
By the way, i have another question.Can you please help me ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019399/cant-access-private-member-of-singleton-class-when-upgrade-from-vs2003-to-vs2005